# List all data in sql table, row by row

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqlcommand

I am trying to list all data in a table, but it only returns the first row, it doesn't loop the whole table.
i need to return the data as strings, because I will use it in a ASMX web service.

And the xml schema only returns the first row

```
<String> data in row 1<String>
```

i want it to return somthing like this:

```
<String> data in row 1<String>
<String> data in row 2<String>
<String> data in row 3<String>
```

and row 1 to n rows....

I have tested the sql statment in VS2012 query builder and there it works fine.
so i need to list out all the data in a way.

**Here is my Code**

```
public String finAllCompaniesForSpesficuserByUserId(String userid)
{
    List<String> l = new List<String>();
    try
    {
        String sql = "SELECT Companies.Name FROM UsersInCompanies INNER JOIN Companies ON UsersInCompanies.CompanyId = Companies.CompanyId WHERE UsersInCompanies.UserId ='" + userid + "'";
        con = new SqlConnection(cs);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adapter.Fill(table);
        con.Open();

        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        dr.Read();

        //while (dr.Read())
        //{
        //    l.Add(dr["Name"].ToString());
        //}

        foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
        {
            return row["Name"].ToString();
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        if (con != null)
            con.Close();
    }
    /*
    foreach (string p in l)
    {
        return p;

    }
    */
    return null;
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction or give me an examples?

Comment: While not directly related to the problem you are presently having, you have created a SQL injection attack vector by constructing SQL yourself => http://unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html

Comment: You already have an example. You have commented it out. Add each row data to the list. Then return the list at the end of the function. Drop the premature returns.

Comment: Are you creating your own xml using stringBuilder?  I hope not, but am asking.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    return row["Name"].ToString();
}
```

you are returning from very first iteration itself.

Comment: my downvote.... im not one for answers that just point out the problems. If you want some points from me, you should give an example of how to fix the problem

Comment: @musefan: Please you do it.i don't need any point buddy , its just the  help i am doing to my fellow programmer.

Comment: Every think works fine now. Im resciving the message as SOAP to my android device and populating a spinner with the items spittet by ",". Whop whop. made my day!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of returning immediately in the for-loop either use a `yield` statement (and change the return type to `IEnumerable<String>` - which just moves the `for` loop out of the function and somewhere else) or use a `StringBuilder` to build the resulting string.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(table.Rows.Count * 30); /* 30 is arbitrary */ 

foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
    // yes 3 separate calls are correct
    sb.Append("<String>");
    sb.Append(row["Name"].ToString())
    sb.Append("</String>\n");
}

/* after closing, cleaning up */
return sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works fine now:)
Have stuggle with that for a while!

Answer (score 0):

> Try this

```
    var temp=  "<String>" +
            string.Join("</String>\n<String>", dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x["Name"].ToString())) +
            "</String>";
```